# Build realm sync project with new Android (Java) project

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, realm

I'm having trouble getting my realm dependencies right for an Android Java project.

I started [a new project](https://github.com/Diederikjh/realm-play) to try and isolate the problem.

The project is using Android Gradle Plugin Version 7.1.0 and Gradle version 7.2 and Android studio 2021.1.1

I [followed the instructions for installing realm in the project](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/android/install/).  And it builds and runs when I just call

```
Realm.init(context);
```

When I try to initialize a synced realm however (buy following the getting [Sync quick start guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/android/quick-start-sync/#std-label-android-client-quick-start-sync)) I can't seem to get the right imports for the `App` and `AppConfiguration` classes.

The build fails with

```
error: cannot find symbol
        App app = new App(new AppConfiguration.Builder("XXXYYYZZZ")
```

In my older project I see the imports were

```
import io.realm.mongodb.App;
import io.realm.mongodb.AppConfiguration;
```

But that doesn't seem to be found by Android studio.

(The `RealmTransformer` part of the `import io.realm.transformer.RealmTransformer` line is in read, which is probably not a great sign, but I can't see any warnings in the IDE about it, and it seems to build fine)

Application level gradle file as below

I've tried various combinations of `api` vs `implementation` and `kapt` vs `annotationProcessor`.  Also did "invalidate caches and restart".  But nothing worked.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.21'
    ext.realm_version = '10.10.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-transformer:$realm_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

import io.realm.transformer.RealmTransformer
android.registerTransform(new RealmTransformer(project))


android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "guru.diederik.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'

    api "io.realm:realm-annotations:$realm_version"
    api "io.realm:realm-android-library:$realm_version"
    api "io.realm:realm-android-kotlin-extensions:$realm_version"
    kapt "io.realm:realm-annotations-processor:$realm_version"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the install instructions have been updated.  Applying them have now worked, and the project builds.

Project level gradle file that works.

```
buildscript {
    ext.realm_version = '10.10.1'
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realm_version"
    }
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And app level gradle file that works

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-transformer:$realm_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "guru.diederik.myapplication"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

realm {
    syncEnabled = true
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```